# instagram api. hot to get the user's list of subscribers?

Tags: c#

using the instagram documents I try to count user's list of subscribers.token is returned correctly, but if I try to get the users's list it's always error 400 code. 
if someone found how to fix that tell me please how. I tryed with the instasharp but can not figured out how to use 'subscribers output method'. the internet has no good example with the explains for the beginner. using a library xNet

```
public string tok = Gettoken();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllText("tokken.txt", followby());
    //MessageBox.Show(Gettoken());
}

public static string Gettoken()
{
    string clientID = "**********************";
    string clientSecret = "****************";
    string redirect_uri = "https://localhost";

    var info = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" + clientID + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri + "&response_type=token";

    var request = new HttpRequest();
    request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();
    HttpResponse response = request.Get(string.Format(info));

    string str = response.ToString();
    string pattern = @"([0-9a-f]{32})";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    Match match = regex.Match(str);
    return match.Groups[1].Value.ToString();
}

string followby()
{
    var info = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/23423443/follows?access_token=" + tok;

    var request = new HttpRequest();
    request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();
    HttpResponse response = request.Get(string.Format(info)); //error

    return response.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you haven't included the permission scope of your application while getting your access token. I see you're trying to get the users' Follows and Followed-By list. For this you need to include `"&scope=follower_list"` in your URL for obtaining access token.

User will be asked that your application is trying to read your Follow list, if the user approves only then you can get this type of data.

Read https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/ for further information.